# How to prevent overlap in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, collision-detection, overlap, p5.js

BEFORE YOU READ:
THIS IS P5.js
https://p5js.org

Ok, a simple form of the question I am asking is this, look at the code below:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000,650);
}

var x = 0;
function draw() {

    background(200,200,200);

    if(x+50<750){x+=17;}
    fill(0,0,0);
    rect(750,0,250,550);
    fill(0,0,255);
    rect(x,height/2,50,50);


}
```

As seen if you run it, the square will "run-over" the black barrier rather than stop just next to it, because the increments are of 17, whereas if the increment was 1 , it would perform perfectly. I attempted to vamp the framerate up to 6000 but for obvious reasons this did not work. ***THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE, BUT HOW (I am making platform physics) WOULD I HAVE A DYNAMIC WAY TO MAKE THE SQUARE SMOOTHLY COLLIDE WITH THE BARRIER?***

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: Check out [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) on collision detection. that's for Processing, but all of the same ideas apply to P5.js.

Comment: lol ok__________

Comment: it appears to do dissapear in one frame. slow the frameRate(2); and change the x speed to an irregular number... it will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `x` position plus `width` of rect to detect collision. If sum is greater than your obstacle position when handle new `x`. Here is simplified example of how it can be handled.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 650);
}

var x = 0,
dir = 1,
rectSize = 50;

function draw() {
  var acc = 17 * dir,
      nextX = x + acc;
      if (nextX + rectSize > 750) {
        dir = -1;
        x = 750 - rectSize;
      } else if (nextX < 0 ) {
        dir = 1;
        x = 0;
      }
  background(200, 200, 200);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  rect(750, 0, 250, 750);
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  rect(x, height / 2, rectSize, rectSize);

  x += acc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

There is library [p5.collide2D](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D) for collision detection, I adivse you to check it out.

Comment: I see in the snippet it still overlaps on collision

Comment: i will look at collide 2d